# Replace apex:InputField

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

we have a visualforce page which is exceeding 135 kb viewState limit. The page uses data of past five years from database with **`<apex:inputField>`** in **`<apex:repeat>`** and renders data.
Now is there any way to replace **`<apex:inputField>`** with html input tag?

Answer (score 1):

If your view state is getting exceeded then you should go with Javascript remoting. Records fetched with this methods are not included in view state at all.

Check example [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Before taking any action you should first establish whether the problem is with the view state that is:

1. the non-transient fields of your controller
2. a consequence of the apex tags

Both will increase as you present more rows, but 1) is much easier to fix than 2).

The [View State Tab](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_tab_view_state.htm) lets you establish this